# docker-compose command use gem:foreman about Ruby on Rails and not release server.pid when stop container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

I use docker-compose on Ruby on Rails and have a trouble.

In docker-compose, I use `command` and direct `foreman`.

When stop docker-compose by Ctrl-c and restart by `docker-compose up`, Rails cause an error `A server is already running. Check /www/tmp/pids/server.pid.`.

Of course, I know `rm tmp/pids/server.pid` is one of the solutions, but this is bothersome every time.

So, I want a solution of this circumstance.

I write Procfile and docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile(for reference)

Procfile.dev:

```
app: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
webpacker: bin/webpack-dev-server
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: "bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev"
    volumes:
      - .:/www
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=""
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgresql-webapp-data:/var/lib/postgresql
volumes:
  postgresql-webapp-data:
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.3-alpine

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV ROOT_PATH /www
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --update --no-cache alpine-sdk tzdata postgresql-dev nodejs postgresql-client curl && curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh
ENV PATH /root/.yarn/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir $ROOT_PATH
WORKDIR $ROOT_PATH

ARG BUNDLE_OPTIONS

ADD Gemfile $ROOT_PATH/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $ROOT_PATH/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --path vendor/bundle -j4 ${BUNDLE_OPTIONS}
ADD . $ROOT_PATH
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: So what's a question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English.
I want remove server.pid when stop docker-compose.
Please tell me how to implement.

Comment: try to replace command with `rm -rf tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev`

Comment: Thanks! I prepare a /bin/server (that is execution file)  instead your advise and write `rm -rf tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev` in the file.
Actually, I try what you say, but did not the behavior as expected.
Appreciate your support!